# How to count orders per customer

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of customers how have all made a number of orders. I want to create a new column which will tell me which order was 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc for each customer e.g.:

```
Customer   Order #  New Flag 
customer 1  12345    1st Order
customer 1  12346    2nd Order
Customer 2  12347    2nd Order
Customer 2  12344    1st Order
Customer 3  11112    1st Order
Customer 3  12332    3rd Order
Customer 3  11123    2nd Order
```

Comment: Welcome! Try put to **C2** `=COUNTIF($A$1:A2;A2)` and fill it down

Comment: In your example, for Customer 3, how are we expected to know the logic where you have the 3rd order appear prior to the 2nd order? Same for Customer 2, where the 2nd is above the 1st. We can assume it's based on order#, but you didn't mention anything about the meaning of that column

Comment: This might be a possible approach but I am leaving it as a comment since I am not converting Ranks to Ordinal numbers as expected by you. In Excel 365 I though RANK with FILTER might work but RANK does not accept Array only Ranges? See this screenshot --> https://i.imgur.com/Dc3cs6L.png

Comment: @patkim You should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand your question. Try this solution. It is possible to create a Single formula in a cell but it gets too long so I am using two column approach. If you have Excel 365 you may shorten it by using LET function.

See below screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Formula in E3 is

```
 =1+SUMPRODUCT(($C$3:$C$12=C3)*($D$3:$D$12<D3))
```

and in F3 to convert it to Ordinal system as required by you.

```
=E3&IF(OR(VALUE(RIGHT(E3,2))={11,12,13}),"th",IF(OR(VALUE(RIGHT(E3,1))={1,2,3}),CHOOSE(RIGHT(E3,1),"st","nd","rd"),"th")) & " Order"
```

Note that in older versions of Excel the second formula might need to be created as an Array Formula by simultaneously pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from within the formula bar to create it as an Array Formula. It might not work correctly otherwise.

If the List Separator in your region is ; instead of , you would need to replace commas by semicolon in the same formula.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Office 365, you can try:

```
C2: ="Order # " & MATCH(B2,SORT(FILTER($B:$B,$A:$A=A2),1))
```

and fill down

*For efficiency, I would suggest converting the formula to use a table with structured references eg:*

```
="Order # " & MATCH([@[Order '#]],SORT(FILTER([Order '#],[@Customer]=[Customer]),1,1))
```

- Filter the Order # to return only those associated with the customer on the same row.
- Sort those order numbers ascending
- Use the `MATCH` function to return the position of the order number

[image]

*If you must show ordinal numbers in your output, I will leave that conversion to you*